Kivy not displaying images: "Image not found" error for all image paths
I'm new to Kivy, and each time I try to display an image in my app, I get an "Image not found" error. I tried using different image files, but none of them seem to work. I still can't figure out why Kivy isn't loading the images.
I'm using Kivy version 2.3.0.
The images are located in the same folder as the Python file or in subdirectories.
I've tried using absolute paths as well, but the issue persists.
import os
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.app import App

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        image_path = "kivymd/images/transparent.png"
        
        layout = BoxLayout()
        
        if os.path.exists(image_path):
            print(f"Image found: {image_path}")
            img = Image(source=image_path)
            layout.add_widget(img)
        else:
            print(f"Image not found: {image_path}")
          
        return layout

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()




Where is your image folder located in comparison to the file  you are trying to load your image from?
